# CSS Make a rounded corner be a circle with percentage radius

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add rounded corners to my images. They are Bootstrap 4 responsive images (With the class `img-fluid`), so I don't want to use something like `border-radius=15px`, because if the images become very small (on a small viewport), the rounded off corners will take up most of the image, and when the images are very large, the rounding will be barely notiecable.

I can use `border-radius=15%;`, but if my image is not a square, the rounded corners are elliptical instead of circular. I can fix this with `border-radius=15%/10%;`, but then I have to adjust this ratio to match the aspect ratio of each individual image.

Is there a way to round the corners of a Bootstrap 4 responsive image, such that the rounding is always circular, and always the same ratio of the image width or height, regardless of the aspect ratio of the image?

I would prefer to do this with only CSS. I could do it using Javascript, but I will only really have three different aspect ratios of image in this application, so it would be easier to just create three different classes.

Comment: nop, you need a square to draw a circle from via radius. objec-fit could help or an svg used as a mask, but just a guess :)

Comment: Without javascript you mean? Because with javascript it is a piece of cake.

Comment: @JoostS Yeah, I would prefer without javascript. Because if I have to use javascript, it would end up being easier for me to just create three different classes for the three different aspect ratios of images I'll use in practice.

Comment: You can use a class in javascript without any problem. Just use `$('img.yourclass').each()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky solution, but we can use CSS3 `vw` or [viewport width](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) to achieve something close to what you want. `border-radius:5vw;` will reduce or increase the % based on the total width of the viewport.

The size of the *image* wont matter just the viewport. But you can get pretty good results none the less.

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:5vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I suggest you just use JS for this.

Comment: I guess this is technically the closest option to what I want, but my images are responsive and scale with the viewport, so this won't really work. I ended up just using `border-radius: 15%/10.1%;`, and then adjusted the aspect ratio as needed for each of my 3 different sizes of images. If I needed this to work with arbitrarily-sized images, I would have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript solution**

Here is your 15% border radius with the help of some javascript (jQuery):

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    $('img').each(function(){
       $(this).css('border-radius',($(this).width()*0.15)+'px');
    });
});
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(window).resize();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqepMQ

PS. I would add a 'standard' border-radius to the image with CSS (e.g. '30px'), so that the image appears roughly correct before the `$(document).ready()` kicks in.

---

**Non-javascript solution**

Wrap the image in a container and use the before and after pseudo elements on the image and the container to overlay 4 rounded corner images on the image. This assumes and requires that the background is a solid color. These images (preferably SVG) should be/are squares, so it is easy to size them by manipulating just their width. This width can be set relative to the image width (by using a percentage).

Personally I think that this solution is quite messy, due to the extra DOM elements and the images with the fixed background colors. I would choose the javascript solution for its simplicity.